# Magento 2 - Show random products on cart page

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

I want to show random products on cart page related to cart items.I can't add cross sell products from admin to each product one by one. So I need help to show cart items related products (category based) programmatically.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `orderRand()` method.

**You can do:**

```
$productsCol = $this
        ->getCategory($id)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize(3);

$productsCol->getSelect()->orderRand();

$products = $productsCol->getItems();
```